# SQL calculation within VB.Net not working

Tags: sql, vb.net

This is a pre-assignment for a class I'm in. Supposed to be pretty simple and act as a warm-up, but I can't get it working. Basically the code is bringing in a test database and performing a calculation. In this case I'm trying to find the highest average batting average in a set of baseball players.

So my end result should be the name of the player with the highest batting average, or a few players if they are tied for the highest average.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Baseball.accdb"
    Dim sqlStr As String = "SELECT * FROM Players"
    Dim dataAdapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, connStr)

    dataAdapter.Fill(dt)
    dataAdapter.Dispose()

    Dim average, pastAverage, highestAverage As Double
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        average = CDbl(dt.Rows(i)("hits/atBats"))
        If average > pastAverage Then
            highestAverage = average
        End If
        pastAverage = average
    Next

    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
        If dt.Rows(i)("hits/atBats") = highestAverage Then
            lstBoxHighest.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("name"))
        End If
    Next

  End Sub
End Class
```

The debugger won't go past the "average = Cdbl(dt.Rows(i)("hits/atBats"))" line in the first For Loop. Can I not do calculations like that in the loop? I am sure the column titles (hits and atBats are correct)

The database looks like this in case you were wondering:

```
name              Team              atBats        hits

Derek Jeter       New York Yankees  511           158
Joe Mauer         Minnesota Twins   545           174
etc...
```

Thanks!

Comment: hits is a column name ,and atBats is a column name. I am trying to find batting average by dividing hits by atBats. So it should be a calculation. Should I try creating a new column by writing SELECT name, hits/atBats as batting average FROM Players?

Comment: I added what the database looks like so you can see the atBats and hits columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing some object refs:

```
average = CDbl(dt.Rows(i).item("hits") / dt.Rows(i).item("atBats"))
```

and like that for the rest of them.  VB needs an `dt.Rows(i)` reference because those are 2 different columns.  With "hits/atBats", it cant know those are individual columns.

Shorthand, but kind of masks that they are different cols/items is like you had it:

```
average = CDbl(dt.Rows(i)("hits") / dt.Rows(i)("atBats"))
```

Comment: VB.Net does not actually require the `Item` property. `dt.Rows(i)("hits") / dt.Rows(i)("atBats")` is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: I know. I was explicit it to help the OP understand the internal structure/contents of the DT and obj refs in general.  It was kind of worded wrong though, thanks.

Comment: Thank you! I was getting very frustrated

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: it's not a direct answer to the question.

Instead of pulling all the data to the client and then using two loops to find a name you can do all calculations on db-side and grab only needed rows and columns (in your case just `name`) with a query that may look like

```sql
SELECT name
  FROM Players
 WHERE atBats / hits = 
(
  SELECT MAX(atBats / hits)
    FROM Players
)
```

Output:

```
|        NAME |
|-------------|
| Derek Jeter |
```